# How to add List to SharePoint from Console App?

Tags: sharepoint, console-application

I am trying to add List to a site via console App. Here is what I have so far.

```
namespace spConsole
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://spdev.com/SitePages/Home.aspx"))
        {
            SPWebCollection webcoll = site.AllWebs;

            SPWeb web = webcoll["SubSite1"];

            SPList newList = web.Lists.Add("New List", "Description", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);                             

        }
    }
}
}
```

I am getting the following error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid' to 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList'

Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not created the instance of SPSite

Please follow this link to create new list programatically

http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-sharepoint-list-programmatically.html

OR

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Create-List-Programmatically-in-SharePoint-274.php

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong. I guess I was trying to define SPList newList with out actually having a list in the site.